# How do I correctly implement the tests requiring USAGE in the healthcheck.sh script from a healthcheck in my docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have an application that requires mariadb/mysql database.  When putting both in the same docker-compose.yml, I run into an issue as the application is trying to access the database before it is fully started up.  This is a common issue and is referenced multiple times across the internet.  The solution is to implement a healthcheck on the mariadb container and have the application container depend_on the condition of service_health, aka the mariadb healthcheck passes.

MariaDB contains a healthcheck script location at [/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/healthcheck.sh) so I figured this would be pretty simple to implement.  However, after searching I am unable to find  solution, nor get anything but the --connect test to come back successful.

The following is my db portion of my docker-compose.yml file.  I pulled out the web service as frankly it's irrelevant as it is just checking for the service_healthy condition of the db service.

```
---
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - mariadb-vol:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MysqlRootPassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=myappdb
      - MYSQL_USER=myapp
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=MysqlRootPassword   
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
volumes:
  mariadb-vol:
```

It looks like the connect test passes, but the innodb_initialized fails.

I tried connecting to the docker container and running the /usr/local/bin/bin.healthcheck.sh script directly in bash but the --innodb_initialized still fails.  I think that's related to the fact I'm logging into the container and it puts me as root.  I'm not sure what user account the database is initialized as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `innodb_initialized` failure is an unfortunate lack of documentation now corrected with [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh-script/).

The newer versions of that MariaDB container now include a `healthcheck` user with credentials populated in the `.my-healthcheck.cnf` file which will now work the the the compose file in the question.

So update yaml configuration (replacing `MYSQL_*` with `MARIADB_*`) is:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - mariadb-vol:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=MysqlRootPassword
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=myappdb
      - MARIADB_USER=myapp
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=MysqlRootPassword
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Prior to this change in the [Docker Official Images](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/14936), 10.4.30, 10.5.31 10.6.14, 10.9.7, 10.10.5, 10.11.4, 11.0.2, 11.1.1-rc is where the original question poster had troubles.

In this case there wasn't a `healthcheck` user created or a `.my-healthcheck.cnf` file to provide credentials to perform the `--innodb_initialized` check. As such, the `healthcheck.sh` was run as root and, without a configuration file including a password, an empty root password was used. One solution for those with an older initialized directory is to include the root password in a configuration file like and pass this is file in as a volume on `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`:

healthcheck.cnf

```
[mariadb-client]
user=root
password=MysqlRootPassword
```

Another is to create `healthcheck` user and a `.my-healthcheck.cnf` file exactly how the updated entrypoint would have created the `healthcheck` user:

```
    CREATE USER healthcheck@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'myVeryRandomPassword';
    CREATE USER healthcheck@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'myVeryRandomPassword';
    CREATE USER healthcheck@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'myVeryRandomPassword';
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO healthcheck@'127.0.0.1';
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO healthcheck@'::1';
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO healthcheck@localhost;
```

```
echo -e "[mariadb-client]\\nuser=healthcheck\\npassword=myVeryRandomPassword\\nprotocol=tcp\\n" |
   docker exec -i runningcontainer bash -c 'cat > /var/lib/mysql/.my-healthcheck.cnf'
```

If you are initializing and older volume and don't want to put a password into a configuration file, there is an alternative.

The container environment variable `MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER=1` will create a `mysql@localhost` user with unix socket authentication. The default grants on this (USAGE), are enough to test `innodb_initialized` (see top of script). For this the compose file would look like where I have, for clarity only, emphasized an older version:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.29
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--su-mysql", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - mariadb-vol:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=MysqlRootPassword
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=myappdb
      - MARIADB_USER=myapp
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=MysqlRootPassword
      - MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER=1   
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: This fixed the issue.  I'd have thought this would have been documented better!

Comment: [contributions welcome](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/docker-and-mariadb/). Like many open source projects we're stretched in the services we try to provide.

Comment: I always end up with error: failed switching to "mysql": operation not permitted. Any idea?

Comment: The container runtime environment is preventing the switching of the user to `mysql`. Sounds worthy of a new question showing environment information on OS/container runtime/kernel and is this occurring on the heathcheck, or entrypoint?

Comment: @danblack You mention in your update that `"--su-mysql"` is not needed anymore, yet it is still present in the yaml sample. Does the answer need updating?