# symfony mariadb ssl connection not working anymore after updating php from 8.1 to latest 8.2.8

Tags: php, symfony, mariadb

After updating my php image from 8.1 to 8.2.8 symfony is not working with mariadb connections using ssl. Not sure if anything happened on the new php verrsion.

Symfony error
`An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))`

docker database log
`2023-07-17 17:51:27 19 [Warning] Aborted connection 19 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.26.0.3' (This connection closed normally without authentication)`

docker compose

```
database:
    container_name: database
    image: "mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}
        target: /var/logs/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_CERTS_DIR}
        target: /etc/certs/
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime:ro
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_BACKUP_DIR}
        target: /opt/mysql/backup
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_BACKUP_SCRIPT_DIR}
        target: /etc/periodic/daily
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      app_network:
    command:
      [
        "mysqld",
        "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",
        "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci",
        "--require_secure_transport=OFF",
        "--bind-address=0.0.0.0",
        "--ssl-key=/etc/certs/server-key.pem",
        "--ssl-cert=/etc/certs/server-cert.pem",
        "--ssl-ca=/etc/certs/ca-cert.pem",
      ]
```

symfony dbal config

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version:    '%env(DATABASE_VERSION)%'
        dbname:            '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
        host:              '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
        port:              '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
        user:              '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
        password:          '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
        driver:            '%env(DATABASE_DRIVER)%'
        charset:            UTF8
        options:
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY: '%DATABASE_PUB_KEY%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT: '%DATABASE_PRIV_KEY%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%DATABASE_CA_CERT%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT: false
```

docker image

```
# FROM php:8.1.1-fpm
FROM php:8.2-fpm



RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update \
    &&  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        locales \
        apt-utils \
        git \
        libicu-dev \
        g++ \
        libpng-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        unzip \
        libpq-dev \
        nodejs \
        wget \
        apt-transport-https \
        lsb-release \
        ca-certificates

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen  \
    &&  locale-gen

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    &&  mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash 
    # &&  mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin

RUN docker-php-ext-configure \
            intl \
    &&  docker-php-ext-install \
            pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring gd xsl

RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

# RUN npm install --global yarn

RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev; \
pecl install imagick; \
docker-php-ext-enable imagick;

RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install iputils-ping git
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096

WORKDIR /var/www/

RUN echo 'deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.symfony.com/apt/ /' |  tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/symfony-cli.list
RUN apt update
RUN apt install symfony-cli

RUN symfony new --version=6.* --no-git --dir=./app

RUN apt install -y ffmpeg

WORKDIR /var/www/app

EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: which mariadb version? Note `mysqld` in the command isn't needed (and will break in [11.0+](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-server-docker-official-images-healthcheck-without-mysqladmin/)). All non `--ssl-*` cmd options are unnecessary to as they are default. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076357/how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-tests-requiring-usage-in-the-healthcheck-sh-scr/76089040#76089040) are you making a connection before mariadb is ready?

Comment: `mariadb-10.9.2`. I tried removing `mysqld` command line with no effect. Database should be ready with `depends_on` on my app

Comment: could try to narrow it down a little further in the php version and put in a [php issue](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues). There's a few minor mysql changes in the [php log](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php) so it could be a regression.