# I have a docker compose which uses a mariadb database that I can't connect to. [Errno 111]

Tags: python, mysql, database, docker, mariadb

I've set up a database within my docker compose with the folllowing values:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Worker
    user: root
    restart: always
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql+pymysql://user1:user1@db/user1
      REDIS_URL: redis://cache:6379
      UPLOAD_PROVIDER: s3
      FILE_QUARANTINE_URL: http://file-quarantine:7000/quarantine-file
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/xxx
    depends_on:
      - cache
    networks:
        default:
        internal:
        cf-net:

  file-quarantine:
    build:
      context: deployer/file-quarantine
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "7001:7000"
    environment:
      CLAMD_HOST: 'clamav'
    networks:
      default:
      internal:

  clamav:
    build:
      context: deployer/clamav
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3310:3310"
    volumes:
      - .data/clamav_db:/var/lib/clamav
    networks:
      default:
      internal:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user1
      MYSQL_USER: user1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: user1
    volumes:
      - .data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        internal:
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  cache:
    image: redis:4
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - .data/redis:/data
    networks:
        internal:

  mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1025:1025" # smtp server
      - "8025:8025" # web ui
    networks:
        default:
        internal:

networks:
    cf-net:
      driver: bridge
    default:
    internal:
        internal: true
```

This is the full error message I'm currently getting:

```
worker-1      | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

There is also this error from within another container which should be running on the same network:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.24.0.9' (using password: NO)
```

I've tried changing the ports and making sure everything is reachable from within the container to the database which looks like it is.

Comment: The first error can happen if you have the wrong port in your database configuration, or if you're not waiting long enough for the database to start up.  The second error just looks like you're not supplying the password.  The database configuration on its own probably isn't enough to understand these client problems; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm using the default port which should be 3306 for mariadb? And would the password being the same as the username / database name cause an issue?

Comment: `(using password: NO)` - you did set a password should the connection should use this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076357/how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-tests-requiring-usage-in-the-healthcheck-sh-scr/76089040#76089040) for layering service dependencies.